# Display value (result of formula) rather than formula in fomula bar

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the problem:

My table is very large and the column width is not enough to show all the text in it.
Since the text/value is generated by a formula in the cell, if I click on the cell, the Formula Bar will display the formula and not the value. Of course.

However, I think it is very useful to quickly know the content of the cell generated by the formula. If I expand the column width every time is not quick and clean.

Do you know if there is a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not a way to show it in the formula bar if there is a formula in the cell.

The best thing I can suggest is to leave row 1 empty and merge A1:N1 together or similar, ,freeze row 1 if necessary

then put this formula into A1

```
=INDIRECT(CELL("address"))
```

When you select a cell on the sheet , press F9 on the keyboard and you can read the full value of the active cell in row 1

With a little VBA in the sheet you can also have it automatically update the cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent solution! +1. As an alternative, a tooltip can be shown at the mouse pointer location (code inside `Worksheet_SelectionChange`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution.  Simply assign a key to the following macro:

```
Sub DislayCellValue()
  Dim outp As String
  outp = "The value in the active cell is:" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & ActiveCell.Value
MsgBox Prompt:=outp
End Sub
```

To display the value in a cell, click on the cell and hit Ctrl-(key).This might be helpful.